# How to substitute " with &quot; in perl

Tags: perl, quotes, substitution

I want to substitute all `"` in the string `$input` with `/&quot;` and I come up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser );
my $q = CGI -> new;
print $q -> header();
$input = 'abc"abc';
(my $output = $input) =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
print "input = $input\n";
print "output = $output\n";
```

However, the `$output` is not changed. How can I get this right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a module suitable for the purpose, such as [`HTML::Entities`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEntities):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;

my $input = 'abc"abc';
print encode_entities($input);
```

**Output:**

```
abc&quot;abc
```

In your code, the variable `$input` is not changed because you are using parentheses to avoid it.

```
(my $output = $input) =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
```

This will enforce the assignment to happen first, overruling precedence. Then the regex substitution is applied to `$output`. When I run your code, I get the expected output:

```
input = abc"abc
output = abc&quot;abc
```

If you do not get this output, I expect the quotes in your string is something different than you think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just find that I have made a silly mistake.
I run the script and output the result on the browser. Obviously the &quot; will be changed into " by the browser.